# Is it possible to have multiline calls to commands in the django template language?

Tags: django

I have a Django template that I include in other templates (a "snippet") with a lot of variables.  The makes for a very long very hard to read line.  Is there anyway to split long commands over multiple lines?  For example, instead of:

```
{% include "mySnippet.html" with var1="a" var2="b" var3="c" %}
```

something like:

```
{% include "mySnippet.html" with 
     var1="a" 
     var2="b" 
     var3="c" %}
```

(I'm using Django 1.6 if that makes a difference).

Comment: If the vars are specific to the included template, then create a context processor.

Comment: I'm new to Django so I'm not sure I understand your comment.  But I don't think a context processor will help because I am repeatedly including the same snippet with different variables in a single template.  (I want to solve this particular problem but I'm curious about the root question which is "can you have multiline command in a template?")"

Comment: No this isn't allowed as a part of the core django templating system, but there is discussion about it on the mailing list. http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Revisiting-multiline-tags-td4483342i80.html

Comment: Thanks schillingt - That is what I thought. (Is it for performance reasons?)  If you had submitted your comment as an answer I would have marked it as correct.